Jupyter Lab 4.x and ipywidgets
I am currently working in JupyterLab version 4.1.6 and having problems with sliders from ipywidgets (version 8.1.2). I wanted to display 2D slices from a 3D image, where the slider would control the current slice being displayed, along the z-axis, but the slider keeps showing the same slice each time and I cannot interact with it.
After some searching, I assumed this was a compatibility issue between different version of JupyterLab and ipywidgets (also checked that everything was indeed enabled, as some discussions instructed), but I wasn't able to figure out if any version of ipywidgets was supported in JupyterLab 4.x or not... Does anybody have any further information on this?

You include no minimal, reproducible example. Or even code. Current ipywidgets works well with JupyterLab 4.1. Some differences do occur though in how certain things are linked. I suspect you didn't install ipympl and are trying to do something that needs that in current JupyterLab and Jupyter Notebook 7+; however, that is pure speculation based on your lack of details and/or minimal, reproducible example. Please read How do I ask a good question? especially the sections about making a good title and 'Help others reproduce the problem'.
